# I get this error (An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in FileName.exe ) - it occurs by the write line function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

```
Dim outputFile As IO.Path
Dim filepath As String = "PCPT2Database.txt"
'Append a new Entry into PCPT2Database
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    'Declare variables
    Dim newNo As Integer = 0
    Dim NewEmail As String = 0
    Dim NewSurname As String = 0
    Dim NewName As String = 0
    Dim NewCell As Integer = 0
    'Defencive Programming

    If txtName.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtName.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Valid Name")
        txtName.Focus()
    Else : NewName = txtName.Text
    End If
    If txtSurname.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtSurname.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Valid Surname")
        txtSurname.Focus()

    Else : NewSurname = txtSurname.Text
    End If
    If txtEmail.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtEmail.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Valid Email")
        txtEmail.Focus()
    Else : NewEmail = txtEmail.Text
    End If
    If mtbCell.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a 10 digit number")
        mtbCell.Focus()
    End If

    Dim filePath As String = "T2Database.txt"
    Dim intNewNo() As Integer = {}
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim currentRow() As String

    Dim intLoop As Integer

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                ReDim Preserve intNewNo(intCount)

                intNewNo(intCount) = currentRow(0)

                intCount = +1

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("line" & ex.Message & " Its not valid.")

            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    For intLoop = 0 To intCount + 1

    Next
    If IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then

        Using outputFile = IO.File.AppendText(filePath)
            outputFile.WriteLine**(Join({intNewNo(intLoop).ToString, txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, mtbCell.Text, txtEmail.Text}, ","))**
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("Save Successful")
        MessageBox.Show("Add another record", "Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        txtName.Clear()
        txtSurname.Clear()
        mtbCell.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(filePath, ".txt not found.",
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: `intCount = +1`: you probably meant `intCount += 1`. Did you check whether `intNewNo` has something in it (did you debug this code)? Try to use `List<T>` instead of arrays there. Is the empty loop supposed to do something meaningful, in relation to what comes after?

Comment: changing int count to intcount = +1 did help,THANK YOU.

Comment: Right at the top of your code 3 out 5 of the `'Declare Variables` are wrong.  Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: What is the empty For loop supposed to do? `For intLoop = 0 To intCount + 1` ?

Comment: To declare a new entry number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way too much going on in a single method. Dividing your code into methods with a single purpose helps you concentrate on that purpose. I broke the code into Validate, Read, Write, and Clear. This greatly simplifies the button code.

The validating code could be improved with `TryParse` methods and `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but I left it alone.

In the Read code I used a `List(Of T)` to accumulate the values. This does not require you to provide an initial size or use `ReDim Preserve` to add data.

The only reason for `intLoop` is to display the index of an errant line in your message box.

The Write code uses the list in the For loop. I assumed that you meant the empty For loop to surround the writing to the file. I do not understand why you want to add records with all the same data except the number form the list. If this is what you want then resolve the join once outside the loop and then just add the number to the string in the loop.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If Not IsInputValid() Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim filePath As String = "T2Database.txt"
    Dim intNewNo = ReadInputFile(filePath)
    If AppendToDataFile(intNewNo) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Save Successful")
        ClearTextBoxes()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show($"{filePath} not found.", "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsInputValid() As Boolean
    If txtName.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtName.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Valid Name")
        txtName.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    If txtSurname.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtSurname.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Valid Surname")
        txtSurname.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    If txtEmail.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtEmail.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Valid Email")
        txtEmail.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    If mtbCell.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a 10 digit number")
        mtbCell.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Function ReadInputFile(FullFilePath As String) As List(Of Integer)
    Dim filePath As String = "T2Database.txt"
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim intLoop As Integer = 0
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
    Dim NewNum As Integer
    For Each line In lines
        If Integer.TryParse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(","c)), NewNum) Then
            lst.Add(NewNum)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show($"Line Num {intLoop} containing{line} is not valid.")
        End If
        intLoop += 1
    Next
    Return lst
End Function

Private Function AppendToDataFile(intNewNo As List(Of Integer)) As Boolean
    Dim filepath As String = "PCPT2Database.txt"
    If IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        Using outputFile = File.AppendText(filepath)
            For Each number In intNewNo
                outputFile.WriteLine(Join({number.ToString, txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, mtbCell.Text, txtEmail.Text}, ","))
            Next
        End Using
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Private Sub ClearTextBoxes()
    txtName.Clear()
    txtSurname.Clear()
    mtbCell.Clear()
    txtEmail.Clear()
End Sub
```

I am sorry, I didn't have an opportunity to test this code so expect some bugs. It would have been easier if you had provided a bit of sample data from the text file.